# Understanding MultiClass Categorical Decision Tree Structure

Tags: predictive-models, cart, scikit-learn, multi-class

I have printed the structure of a CART decision tree, from sci-kit learn,  but I don’t understand it.

It’s multiclass classification, there are 4 possible labels, and 5 features. There are 5 different values for each feature. This is what the data looks like

```
Label  Feat1  Feat2  Feat3  Feat4  Feat5
 A      A      B      A      C      A
 B      B      A      A      B      B
 C      A      C      C      A      A
 D      A      B      B      D      D
```

In order to discretize these categorical variables, I have used a LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder.

This is the result of printing the structure of the Decision Tree. I know that the gini impurity is the decision tree splitting metric, what I really don’t understand is the top of each box, for example `[X7]= 0.5` and the value.

[image: Decision Tree Structure]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with sklearn but I'd guess that `X[7] <= 0.5` is telling you that the split corresponding to this box is comparing the column of `X` at index 7 to the value of 0.5, with the left branch being for the cases in which the check returns true. As for the `value`, i think that's the counts of each class that made it to this split/node. I base that guess on how some of the leaves have `value` equal to something like `[0,0,0,1]` and a corresponding `gini` of 0.

Comment: As the features have been OneHotEncoded, `X[7] <= 0.5` does not make sense,

Comment: Is it 0 or 1? Then it is true when X[7] == 0 and false otherwise.

Comment: OneHotEncoded features are vectors, they look like this [1000,0100,0010,0001]

Comment: One hot encoding means you've expanded a categorical variable with k levels into generally k or k-1 binary indicators. You said you have 5 features originally and it looks like you have at least 12 after one hot encoding. Just look at the actual x matrix after one hot encoding and you'll see this.